# Cassandra Pagination CPU Utilization Issue

Tags: python-3.x, cassandra

I had developed a python script for pulling the data but it is using only single cpu core and when I do top cassandra is using more than 200% cpu. Going into Idle state since in between GC coming into picture Unable understand how can I convert the code to utilize multiple cores and parallel processing.

```
class PagedResultHandler(object):

def __init__(self, future):
    self.error = None
    self.finished_event = multiprocessing.Event()
    self.future = future
    self.future.add_callbacks(
        callback=self.handle_page,
        errback=self.handle_error)
    self.rows = []
def handle_page(self, rows):
    self.rows += rows

    if self.future.has_more_pages:
        self.future.start_fetching_next_page()
    else:
        self.finished_event.set()

def handle_error(self, exc):
    self.error = exc
    self.finished_event.set()
start_time = time.time()
cluster = Cluster(contact_points=['127.0.0.1'],protocol_version=4)
session = cluster.connect('unit_test')
query = "select * from "+table_name+" where runseq=0"   
print("--Fired Query--->> ", query)
future = session.execute_async(query)
handler = PagedResultHandler(future) 
handler.finished_event.wait()
data = pd.DataFrame(handler.rows)
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
if handler.error:
  raise handler.error
cluster.shutdown()
```

Each table I pull contains more than 3million rows and has lot performance issue. Can I help me how I can Make cpu cores and improve performance

Answer (score 1):

You wont get blazing performance out of python driver, but you can look at cqlsh's copy functions (https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/pylib/cqlshlib/copyutil.py#L229) if you really want to see a fast implementation that can use multiple cores.

On C* side make sure you have enough nodes with adequate hardware (ssds, multiple cores, >16gb of ram). If using sub 8gb heaps etc don't expect much out of it. Cassandra/JVM (with default settings) are designed to fully utilize the server as much as it can, not share resources so expect high CPU.

Comment: So whats exactly difference between concurrent process[link](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/datastax-python-driver-multiprocessing-example-for-improved-bulk-data-throughput) and pagination type of fetching [link](https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/query_paging.html). We are presently utilizing pagination to pull the data. Due to some restrictions on product side we use single node cassandra with 20+ cores,100+ gb of Ram and ssd hardrive